# QGIS Wien 2.8. Openlayers plugin doesn't work

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-openlayers-plugin, qgis-2.8

I have installed the latest version of QGIS wien 2.8. Windows 8.1 downloaded the stand alone version from official QGIS website.

I had to uninstall the latest one I had because Openlayers plugin was downloaded and installed but one day it stopped appearing in my toolbar.

So I uninstalled and removed everything and installed again, but the problem remains, just as with the previous one.

Can anybody help me with this issue?

Comment: Is the plugin activated?

Comment: Please clarify in case this is not a duplicate.

Comment: plugin is installed, do I have to activate it? how? In other plugins, I didn't have to activate them. If you mean doing right click and activate it for the toolbar, it doesn't show up in the options. Can anybody help me please?

Comment: @underdark what do I have to clarify? Is there any additional info I have to provide? If so, let me know please ;)

Comment: Problem solved thanks to @underdark it was in the submenu "Web" Why?? -No idea.